# std::chrono::system_clock::now() without auto

Tags: c++, auto, c++-chrono

I have one little question:
How can i write the following code **without** `auto`.

```
auto a = std::chrono::system_clock::now()
/* do something */
auto b = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - a;
```

Comment: check what is the type returned from `now`..

Comment: Oh, I see it now, thanks. :)

Comment: Technically, you could do `decltype(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();` - it doesn't use auto! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

/* do something */

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> b = std::chrono::system_clock::now() - a;
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look in [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point a = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```